# Oracle Apex : Multiple Region Display Selector (RDS) in single page

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I want to create more that one RDS in single page. RDS-1 in region 1 and RDS-2 in Region 2. Following is the format I want my RDS to work.

Region 1

|Tab1|Tab2|Tab3|

---

Region 2

|Tab3|Tab4|Tab5|

I tried to implement RDS in the above format but the resulting page shows in the following format.

Region 1

|Tab1|Tab2|Tab3|Tab3|Tab4|Tab5|

---

Region 2

|Tab1|Tab2|Tab3|Tab3|Tab4|Tab5|

Is there a way around this implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only have 1 RDS per page. Try a different approach.

Assuming that you are using APEX 5 or later you could use static content regions. The template should be set to "Tabs Container".

Your sub regions should now function similarly to an RDS.

You don't get a "show all" option when going this route though.